# Use of quotes with a string value?

Tags: java, android, string

(please note:i got a code,to understand its concepts i am asking this)

In my code there is a declaration `String Password = "";` .Also in my method i have one more code

```
if (Password.equals("")) {
            Password = Password_Text.getText().toString().trim();
            System.out.println("Password", Password);
        }
```

what is this password checks using this equals method.What is the action performed here.Can anyone help......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password here is "String" type and
    Password.equals("")
is used to check is password is empty.
If password is empty then Password_Text is some "EditText" in android and String in that edittext is stored in Password. After that Text in EditText is printed.
Edit text in android is used as
    EditText Password_Text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);

Comment: Password.equals("") is used to check is password is empty or null. - FALSE

Comment: if (password == null) // test for null

Comment: `Password.equals("")` doesn't checks for `null`

Comment: Corrected. Sorry for adding null

Answer (score 2):

String Password = "";
Means there is no value in this String object 'Password' its like empty string object with no single character in it.

For Code Block :

```
if (Password.equals("")) {
            Password = Password_Text.getText().toString().trim();
            System.out.println("Password", Password);
        }
```

Here if checks if there is any value inside String object 'Password' 
Password.equals("") returns true if no single character in this object
false otherwise.

Comment: "there is no value" is a little bit incorrect. Actually `""` is a value itself, just there is no characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

If the field `Password` is blank (not null, blank), then get the value of whatever's entered into `Password_Text`, trim off any leading or trailing whitespaces, and print out the result.

Answer (score 1):

Password = "" means that password is empty and in your if condition it checks that if password is empty then assign the password_text to the password by removing the trailing and leading whitespace of Password_Text.

Answer (score 1):

equals() method use to compare content of String and == use to compare object reference.

Answer (score -1):

It only assign the text you entered in the `Password_Text` field which may be `EditText` to the `String` variable password if the variable password is empty.